# Redirecting desktop traffic to ww.domain.com/home

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have an magento shop running (www.domain) for what i also created an speed door (Accesible through: www.domain.com/home). Now i also installed a mobile theme. the mobile theme is not on a subdomain, but due the design option in Magento, Magento recognizes mobile users en direct them to the mobile site (also just www.domain.com).

Now what i want to do is when desktop users visit www.domain.com that the are redirected to www.domain.com/home (the speeddoor) and when mobile users visit they will go to www.domain.com

I tried adding the following to .htaccess file in the Magento root, but the following code does the opposite. It redirects mobile users to domain.com/home and desktop to domain.com. how can i achieve the opposite.

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home/.*$
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/ [L,R=302]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need a `!` to indicate that you want the user-agent *not* to match the mobile strings:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !"android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/ [L,R=302]
```